# ドライブ直下のフォルダのファイル数と最終更新日時の取得

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

下記の通りドライブ直下にフォルダがあるとします。

- C:\A
- C:\B
- C:\C

これらのドライブ直下のフォルダA,B,Cのみの、ファイル数と最終更新日時を下記の通りEXCEL上に集計したいと考えています。
（A,B,C内のサブフォルダは対象外）

| フォルダ名 | ファイル数 | 最終更新日時 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2021/3/2 |
| B | 100 | 2021/3/4 |
| C | 1000 | 2021/3/9 |

上記のような処理は可能でしょうか？

Comment: vbaタグとbatch-fileタグが指定されていますが、本文にはExcelしか登場していません。どのように実現されることを望んでいるかを明確にしていただけたらと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ちなみにExcelには[Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/excel-%E3%81%A7-power-query-%E5%BC%8F%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-8e5e49a2-01c2-496e-b639-41f98f163238)という機能が搭載されています。これは様々なデータを取得加工しExcel上にテーブルの形で出力する独自言語です。これを使うと求められている表を実現できます。

[データ] - [データの取得] - [Power Queryエディターの起動] を実行し、
[ホーム] - [新しいソース] - [その他のソース] - [空のクエリ] を選択し、
[ホーム] - [詳細エディター] に次のコードを入力し、
[ホーム] - [閉じて読み込む] を実行します。

```
let
    ソース = Folder.Contents("C:\"),
    絞り込み = Table.SelectRows(ソース, each List.Contains({"A", "B", "C"}, [Name])),
    ファイル数追加 = Table.AddColumn(絞り込み, "ファイル数", each List.Count(List.Select([Content][Attributes], each [Kind] <> "Folder"))),
    列順序 = Table.SelectColumns(ファイル数追加,{"Name", "ファイル数", "Date modified"}),
    列名変更 = Table.RenameColumns(列順序,{{"Name", "フォルダ名"}, {"Date modified", "最終更新日時"}})
in
    列名変更
```

これで、次のようなテーブルが入力されるはずです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[データ] - [すべて更新] を実行すると、テーブルの内容が更新され、この場合、ファイル名や最終更新日時が書き変わります。

---

VBAと異なり、どのセルに何のデータが、といった対応情報は不要で、純粋にデータを処理できるたため使いこなせると便利です。

Answer (score 0):

`vba`ならば下記のように[`FileSystemObject.GetFolder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getfolder-method)メソッドを使用することで実現可能です。
最終更新日時は`FileSystemObject`の[`DateLastModified`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property)プロパティを取得するか、[`FileDateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filedatetime-function)メソッドで取得できます。

なおフォルダ内の最新ファイルを取得したい場合は`fso.GetFolder(target).Files`でループを行って最新更新日時を調べてください。

```
Sub test()
    Cells(1, 1) = "フォルダ名" 
    Cells(1, 2) = "ファイル数" 
    Cells(1, 3) = "最終更新日時" 

    Dim target As String
    target = "C:\A"         '対象フォルダ

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Cells(2, 1) = fso.GetFolder(target).Name                'フォルダ名
    Cells(2, 2) = fso.GetFolder(target).Files.Count         'ファイル数
    Cells(2, 3) = fso.GetFolder(target).DateLastModified    '最終更新日時その1
    'Cells(2, 3) = FileDateTime(target)                      '最終更新日時その2

    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```